# Exit full screen control obscures custom control on IPad (GoogleMaps)

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-maps-api-3, fullscreen

In a Google Maps Javascript web page with a custom control, on IPad, if the user goes into full screen, the IPad displays an "X" control which obscures my custom control.

**[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markjackson/vtyrhucq/20/)** demonstrates the issue.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click full screen on iPad (top-right of map)
2. Feel sad because custom control is obscured at top left (screenshot from IPad [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKeK2.png) and embedded at end of post)

**Javascript snippet:**

```
      var customControl = document.getElementById('customControl');

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(customControl);
```

**Possible work-arounds**

- I could put the control in a different position but in my production code there are several controls and I need to put something in the `LEFT_TOP` position. (Or `TOP_LEFT`, the issue also occurs for top-left.)
- I could try to detect iPad and use [`fullscreenControl`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.fullscreenControl) to hide the full screen control. I feel that's Google's job
- I could try to detect iPad and entering full screen and then change the top-margin of my custom control element. I feel that's definitely Google's job.

I have [reported this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128917898) as a Google Maps issue.

Here is a code snippet - oddly this does not reproduce the issue, it does not show the fullscreen control on IPad:

```js
/*
 * declare map as a global variable
 */
var map;

/*
 * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
                    zoom: 11,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.521,-0.12),
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  /* Custom contol */
  var customControl = document.getElementById('customControl');
               map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(customControl);
});

function customControlClicked() {
  alert("Custom control clicked");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#customControl {
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="customControl" onclick="customControlClicked();">Custom</div>
```

Screenshot of the issue taken on IPad
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What about `google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT`? You can refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning but I am not sure this additional full-screen control is added to any of the available control areas as otherwise it wouldn't overlap.

Comment: btw. are you sure this control is added by the API? I don't have an iPad to test and the full screen control doesn't appear in iOS Simulator with iPad.

Comment: The same issue occurs with TOP_LEFT - I tested in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markjackson/vtyrhucq/18/) on an IPad. My guess is the control is being added by IOS Safari. I took the screenshot above on an actual IPad :)

Comment: That might well be the case as the exit full-screen control provided by the API can be seen on the opposite corner. You could reorganize your controls depending on the device type or maybe the browser version, if you can identify when/where this happens.

Comment: Aha! yes it is there on the top right corner.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks for editing the code snippet to fix Google Maps. Weirdly the edited code snippet does not reproduce the issue. In the code snippet the "fullscreen" control is not displayed on IPad. But in the JSFiddle (and on my actual site) the fullscreen control is displayed on IPad. I can't see any difference in the way Google Maps is loaded except that your code snippet includes an API key. My JSFiddle does not include an API key - but my actual site does and the fullscreen control appears on the actual site.

Comment: Hard to tell honestly as I don't have an iPad as I mentioned earlier. Try updating your JSFiddle with the key I used in your above snippet and see if it makes a difference, but I'd be surprised that this control be influenced by the presence of a valid API key (that key was provided by Google for support purposes over here and JSFiddle, so it should work on both domains).

Comment: btw. whether the API full screen control is present or not might depend on the screen size (or map size) but you can force it to be there by using the [`fullscreenControl` option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.fullscreenControl). Set it to `true` in your map options and it "should" be there at all times...

Comment: I have put `fullscreenControl:true` into the map options but the full screen control does not appear in the code snippet. At least the JSFiddle works.

Comment: Strange. Did you test this with other versions of the API? You could also set it to false and push your own control for that, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-replacement

Comment: Hmm. [Looks like](https://dev.to/marvindanig/fullscreen-web-apps-on-ipad-safari--3p9b) full-screen support was only added in Nov 2018 in iOS 12. Perhaps Google haven't noticed yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Google say they aren't going to fix it: in response to my [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128917898), they said

> "After investigation, I see that the iOS is the one that is creating the exit button and was not implemented by the Maps Javascript API, please also note that the exit button also occurs with other web applications as well, since this is out of our scope and documentation, kindly redirect your query to the support page of iOS as they will provide better solutions for the issue."

So unless anyone has a better answer  I will work around the issue by removing the full screen control on IPad.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/markjackson/vtyrhucq/24/) is a JSFiddle with the workaround.

Here is the essential code.

```
  var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 11,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.521,-0.12),
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false
  };
  if ( isIPad() ) {
    mapOptions.fullscreenControl = false;
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), mapOptions);


  function isIPad() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    return (userAgent.match(/iPad/i));
  }
```

Code was adapted from [here](https://bubblin.io/blog/fullscreen-api-ipad)